# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined in ReactJS when trying to render arrays

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using ReactJS to make a website and I keep getting errors like this: *TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined*, when trying to render arrays to the home page. I've tried using hooks and changing what array gets mapped but nothing is working.

Home Page:

```
export default class Home extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            redirect: null,
            post:{
                username:"",
                vidUrl: "",
                title:"",
            }
        };
    }
    
    componentDidMount() {
        const currentUser = AuthService.getCurrentUser();

        if(!currentUser) this.setState({ redirect: "/login"});
        this.setState({ currentUser: currentUser, userReady:true});

        PostService.return().then(result => result.data.videos.map((results) => {
            this.setState({ post:{username:results.username,vidUrl:results.vidUrl,title:results.title}})
            console.log(this.state.post)
        }))

    }
   
    render(){

        if(this.state.redirect){
            return <Redirect to={this.state.redirect} />
        }

        return(
            <div>
                {
                   this.post.map((result) => (
                       <Post key={result._id} username={result.username} caption={result.title} vidUrl={result.vidUrl}/>
                  ))
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Post:

```
export default function Post({username,caption,vidUrl,user}){
    return(
    <div className="header">
        <div className="videoContain">
            <div className="info-Contian">
            <Avatar className="Avatar" />
            <p className="Caption">{username}</p>
            </div>
        <video className="video" src={vidUrl} controls>
          <p>If you are reading this, it is because your browser does not support the 'video' element. Try using the 'object' element listed further down the page.</p>
       </video>
       <br/>
       <FaHeart className="Heart" size="2em" />
       <FaComment className="Comment" size="2em" />
       <br/>
       <p>{caption}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    )
}
```

This is what I am trying to render:

```
{
    "videos": [
        {
            "_id": "612d89284c5c4e9e42cf4fa5",
            "username": "qwerty",
            "title": "stuff",
            "vidUrl": "blob:http://localhost:3000/fd2ba95b-480a-4a46-baf0-8423e1163f7e",
            "comments": [],
            "likes": [],
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "613412b7b13bc4c1b4f4433f",
            "username": "name",
            "title": "also a test",
            "vidUrl": "blob:http://localhost:3000/4ca89ae2-0d1c-4e03-8738-87d7ea29081f",
            "comments": [],
            "likes": [],
            "__v": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Could you please log your `result` to see what is actually in there?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues in your code:

First, to get `map` works, `post` state should be defined as an array

```
this.state = {
    redirect: null,
    post: []
};
```

Second, you should not `setState` in a `map`, once `post` is an array, simple do like this:

```
PostService.return().then(result => this.setState({ post: result.data.videos }))
```

Last one is `this.post` in `render` shoud be `this.state.post`.

Answer (score 0):

State should declare as an array because you are referring list of post. And when receive data from API, save the data array response to state. And using this state to render

```
this.state = {
  redirect: null,
  posts: [],
};

...
PostService.return().then((result) =>
  this.setState({
    posts: result.data.videos,
  }),
);

...    
this.state.posts.map((result) => (
  <Post key={result._id} username={result.username} caption={result.title} vidUrl={result.vidUrl}/>
))
```